# specify username and password in windows xp remote session command line

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a batch file with the following command:

`mstsc.exe /v:SOME_REMOTE_COMPUTER`

I want to also be able to specify the username and password in this batch file, is this possible?

Also, a cmd box opens up when I run this batch file and I have to close it manually, is there a way to exit from the cmd promt automatically after starting up the remote session?

**EDIT:**

I now have:

```
START mstsc.exe /v:SOME_REMOTE_COMPUTER
exit
```

This closes out the cmd promt window. I'm still looking to pass the username & password to the remote session

Comment: I tried adding the command "exit" to the end of the batch file, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, START > All Programs > Accessories > Remote Desktop Connection

Type in the computer name and clock OPTIONS

Check off the box that says save credentials

Now connect, and you will be promted for your username/password. Enter them.

Now you should be connected to the remote computer.

Close out of the remote session.

Create a .bat file that has the following command: `START mstsc.exe /v:SOME_REMOTE_COMPUTER & exit`

Run the .bat file and the remote desktop session should open and submit your saved credetials automatically.